# Typing text from a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I'm new to shell scripting. I'd like to know if there's a command similar to "echo" for displaying text in a terminal, but instead of simply displaying it immediately, it actually types it, like if someone was actually typing on the terminal?

I'd also appreciate it if someone could point me to pages explaining simple scripting like menus and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution :

```
string='foo bar base'
for ((i=0; i<=${#string}; i++)); do
    printf '%s' "${string:$i:1}"
    sleep 0.$(( (RANDOM % 5) + 1 ))
done
```

- `${#variable}` is the length o  f the string
- `printf` can replace `echo` to display string and format output :
- `%s` tell to `printf` to display a string without newline `\n`
- `${string:$i:1}` is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [parameter expansion][1](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to display only a specific letter from the string
- `$(( ))` is some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic
- `$(( ( RANDOM % 5 ) + 1 ))` display an integer : 1 to 5 RANDOMly

**Bonus**

This is a function to use with an argument :

```
matrix(){
    tput setaf 2 &>/dev/null # green powaaa
    for ((i=0; i<=${#1}; i++)); do
        printf '%s' "${1:$i:1}"
        sleep 0.$(( (RANDOM % 5) + 1 ))
    done
    tput sgr0 2 &>/dev/null
}

matrix 'foo bar base'
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was expecting, thanks!
Can you give me a bit of information on the commands you used? I know that the sleep is the time between each letter is displayed, but that's about it.

Comment: it would be more "realistic" if the delay is random, you can use `DELAY=$(echo "$RANDOM/32767.0" | bc -l)` to create randoms between 0 and 1 second and then do `sleep $DELAY`

Comment: @RalphF., good idea, added RANDOM in my script

Comment: How do i make this into a function? Such as `command something` and then it types something?

Comment: See Bonus section of my edited POST

Answer (score 0):

I called it type writer:

```
count=0
echo "enter your name"
read b
sleep 2
a="hello"
a=`echo $a" "$b" nice to meet you"`
while [ $count -lt $((${#a}+1)) ]
do
    x=`expr substr "$a" $count 1`
    if [ "$x" != " " ]
    then
        echo -n $x
        sleep 0.2
    else echo -n " "
    fi
    count=$(($count+1))
done
echo " "
```

Comment: Thanks, but as a beginner I believe sputnick's script is a bit simpler. Will save yours too for reference, though =)